# There are several questions [chatgpt] questions that misses that ChatGPT / OpenAI Chat API are intended to have conversations

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

This is related to [Would posting a question about the common misconception of what ChatGPT does help the site?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/44/12) but is not a duplicate as the previous questions encompass multiple misconceptions, but this one is focused on only one as is explained below:

Several of the first questions tagged [chatgpt](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) look to be missing the OpenAI ChatGPT. OpenAI ChatGPT API is intended to have conversations, so answers look to repeat this feature repeatedly.

Should we create a meta post or a canonical question about the essential use of ChatGPT?

I.E. one of the things to highlight is that while it's possible to have single prompt conversations, that might be omitting the most novelty feature, responding based on the conversation history rather than considering only the last prompt.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Both the title and the text of the question are confusing.

Answer (score 1):

> Should we create a meta post or a canonical question about the essential use of ChatGPT?

I think such a question would either be:

- soliciting marketing copy, perhaps with the lies stripped out; or
- too broad.

These tools might be *intended* to do something specific, but right now, we're basically just [banging particle accelerators together](https://xkcd.com/2021/). What the designers intend something to do, and what that thing *actually does*, are related tangentially at best, and “What is OpenAI's ChatGPT (late July 2023 version) useful for?” is a list question.

“What of XYZ Group's marketing spiel about PlaceholderAI is actually true?” would be an on-topic question, but I don't think it's quite what you're talking about here.